# Add a button to an onDraw call in Android

Tags: android, button

I'm using the code below for drawing simple 2D graphics (which I found on DroidNova - very useful!), and I would like to add a button which I have defined in an XML file (string name and location).  I can't see how to add the button to the screen (while still showing the graphics from the onDraw call...

**Update**

I've updated the code below based on the answer. I can get the rectangle to draw, but it does not show the button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Drawresult();
    }

    protected void Drawresult() {
        // Create a new linear layout to display out custom graphics and a button.
        LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Add our custom panel.
        mainLayout.addView(new Panel(this));

        // Create and setup our button.
        Button myButton = new Button(this);
        myButton.setText("Tap Me");
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 finish();
             }
         });

         // Add our button to the layout.
         mainLayout.addView(myButton);

         // Set this activity's content to our layout.
         setContentView(mainLayout);
     }

     class Panel extends View {
         public Panel(Context context) {
             super(context);
         }

         @Override
         public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

             Rect r = new Rect();
             r.set(60, 60, 260, 77);

             Paint paint = new Paint();
             paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
             paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
             paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

             canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor to this (Assuming you have subclassed Activity. Otherwise post more of your code):

```
protected void Drawresult() {
    // Create a new linear layout to display out custom graphics and a button
    LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    // Add our custom panel
    mainLayout.addView(new Panel(this));

    // Create and setup our button 
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Tap Me");
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Put your click logic here
        }
    });

    // Add our button to the layout
    mainLayout.addView(myButton);

    // Set this activity's content to our layout
    setContentView(mainLayout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had to move the addView(myButton) call to before the addView(new Panel(this)) call to get the button to show, but with this change it works great.  I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DrawResult is extending activity, you need to add a LinearLayout to it instead of the Panel View, and add the Button and the Panel to that layout.